# hook for printing an int in python

Tags: python

I have a nested structure that contains ints, and would like to display them with scientific notation when doing `print` or `pprint` on the structure.
My idea was to add create my overloaded class for int, which when printed would do what I need.
However I can't get a hook for the representation of an int:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class A(int):
    def __str__(self, *args):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

    def __unicode__(self, *args):
        import ipbd; ipdb.set_trace()

    def __repr__(self, *args):
        import ipbd; ipdb.set_trace()

    def __int__(self, *args):
        import ipbd; ipdb.set_trace()

a = A()
a+=2
print(a)
```

None of the breakpoints get called when doing `print(a)`

**EDIT2:**
This code does what I wanted:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

class A(int):
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 0


#    def __add__(self, other):
#        self._value += other
#        return self

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self._value += other
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return "{:,}".format(self._value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{:,}".format(self._value)

a = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(A))
a[0][1]+=123456789
a[0][2]+=100000
pprint(a)
```

Comment: you are not returning anything in your methods

Comment: `a += 2` -- this is a source of problems: the default implementations for `+=`, `+`, `-`, `*`, ... return new `int` instances. You have to override `__add__`, `__mul__`, ... for the correct `A` instance to be returned

Comment: Also, consider using a proxy/wrapper over inheritance. It is usually better in such cases.

Comment: Maybe instead of overloading __str__ on int you should do it on your structure?

Comment: @Hugh I have something like defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)), I'd rather change this to defaultdict(defaultdict(A))

Comment: Please try `print '%d' % a` with your second code block (which supposedly does what you want) - I suspect you'll run into some issues there.

Comment: @Lav I can do print '%d" % int(a), and also overload the __int__ operator, it's good enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the `a+=2`, the `a` variable is reassigned and it becomes an `int`.

Everything that happens afterwards has nothing to do with your `A` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example:

```
class A(int):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{:.2E}".format(self)
```

and then just `print(A(3))` will give you `3.00E+00`

Comment: But this breaks as soon the object is modified, as `int` is immutable. (the `a += 2` statement)

Comment: So override `__add__` as well.

Comment: @MatsLindh: he casts it to A immediately before printing. It will work, but doesn't have any advantage over a formatting function, which OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @HughBothwell He does not cast it - he just creates the object and prints the value. The point being that the `+=` method returns a new `int`, and not his object, which is why printing does not work as the asker wants.